# /usr/bin/env: ruby1.8: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

### Problem

Trying to setup CI Joe (https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe) and I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.8: No such file or directory
```

### What I'm doing

CI Joe is run as www-data, and the command I'm running is

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake -s test
```

When I log in as www-data (sudo su www-data) and execute the same command it works. So I'm trying to figure out what may be wrong.

### Debug Output

```
$ which ruby1.8
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

This problem is similar to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126165/usr-bin-env-ruby-1-8-no-such-file-or

Answer (score 1):

ruby1.8 not found in the user's $PATH. You need set correct $PATH.

Comment: You don't happen to know how I'd set the path for the www-user?

Comment: Second thought, isn't ruby1.8 already in the path since which ruby1.8 returns the path to one ruby1.8 binary.

Comment: Some script clean PATH or all ENV. Change "#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.8" to "#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8".